# keycloak verify email set duration, link expire

Tags: keycloak

in keycloak by default verify email link will expire in 5 minutes.

> Someone has created a XYZ account with this email address. If this was
> you, click the link below to verify your email address
>
> Link to e-mail address verification
>
> This link will expire within 5 minutes.
>
> If you didn't create this account, just ignore this message.

In template looks like this value is taken from somewhere:

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/5c6b123aff9d004a3aa51cd3dfad4e021051fca1/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/email/messages/messages_en.properties#L2

How to increase that value ? Can not find it in admin panel..

thanks

Answer (score 8):

ok I found it
in Realm Settings -> Tokens and under

```
User-Initiated Action Lifespan
```